# Flutter Get Request from API not completed

Tags: flutter, api

I have problem where I don't know. in my flutter project I want to get request. but, I always got error

```
    E/flutter ( 3700): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 396000)
E/flutter ( 3700): ...E PUTIH ALAM  10X20X3CM","ItemType:"Finished Good","ItemClass":"CVL","Po...
E/flutter ( 3700):                                        ^
E/flutter ( 3700): 
E/flutter ( 3700): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter ( 3700): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:935:48)
E/flutter ( 3700): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter ( 3700): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter ( 3700): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter ( 3700): #5      _ScheduleAddState.getStock (package:myfirstapp/scheduleadd.dart:365:24)
E/flutter ( 3700): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3700): 
                               ^
```

but I already generate this json data automatically.

I already stuck in this problem,

this is my API

```
public function StockItemList(){
    $cookie_jar = tempnam("tmp", "cookie");
    //login
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'url',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING      => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS     => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT       => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION  => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR     => $cookie_jar,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    =>'{
            "name"      : "*****",
            "password"  : "*****",
            "company"   :  "**"
        }',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'),
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    //get data
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'url',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $datapo = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    //logout
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'url',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => '{   
            "name" : "*****",
            "password" : "******",
            "company" :   "**"
        }',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data = array();
    $no = 0;
    foreach ($datapo as $doc) {
        $data[$no]['InventoryID'] = $doc->InventoryID->value;
        $data[$no]['Description'] = $doc->Description->value;
        $data[$no]['ItemType'] = $doc->ItemType->value;
        $data[$no]['ItemClass'] = $doc->ItemClass->value;
        $data[$no]['PostingClass'] = $doc->PostingClass->value;
        $data[$no]['TaxCategory'] = $doc->TaxCategory->value;
        $data[$no]['BaseUOM'] = $doc->BaseUOM->value;
        $data[$no]['ItemStatus'] = $doc->ItemStatus->value;
        $no++;
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

this is my flutter

```
getdataStock() async{
// await _getToken();
return await http.get(Uri.parse(_url+"/StockItemList"), headers: _setHeaders());}

Future<String> getStock() async {
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});
var res = await Network().getdataStock();
var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
// if(resBody['success']){
  setState(() {
    print(resBody['StockItem']);
    // _StockItemData = resBody['StockItem'];
  });
// }
setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
});
return "success";}
```

this is my API Flutter

```
getdataStock() async{
// await _getToken();
return await http.get(Uri.parse(_url+"/StockItemList"), headers: _setHeaders());}
```

and in API call another API. where in API Source have 6000+ rows data. it's always lost some " or have "". and this is makes error

Comment: Honestly, it seems more of an API problem rather than Flutter JSON parsing.

Comment: if it like that, the problem in my API or API on I calling / using ? and do you know how I can fix it ? thank you

Comment: The problem is mostly related to how the response body is built. To confirm this, you should try to get this data using CURL or Postman - just to see what kind of response is returned. From your example, I see that your API is built using PHP - if you need to adjust something here, that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: I already testing on my postman too. but, in postman is fine. I thing it has problem on my api calling on my flutter

Comment: or I can directly call External API on my flutter. but how I can build like my api doing. using temp session ?

Comment: @andrysim 
The issue is with API clearly it should be "ItemType" not this one "ItemType

Comment: yes. but, why I can getting data like this ? if I generate data programatically

Comment: Please, copy-paste the response that you get from Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here you can use skip and post on your API to take limited data

```
$skip = (string)(((int)$Page - 1)*50);
    $cookie_jar = tempnam("tmp", "cookie");
    //login
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'Login URL',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING      => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS     => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT       => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION  => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR     => $cookie_jar,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    =>'{
            "name"      : "****",
            "password"  : "****",
            "company"   :  "****"
        }',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'),
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    //get data
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'Get URL ?$top=50&$skip='.$skip,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $datapo = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    //logout
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'Logout URL',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => '{   
            "name" : "****",
            "password" : "****",
            "company" :   "****"
        }',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookie_jar
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
        
    $data = array();
    $no = 0;
    foreach ($datapo as $doc) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-primary" id="add'.$doc->InventoryID->value.'" onclick="addFunction('."'".$doc->InventoryID->value."'".','."'".$doc->Description->value."'".','."'".$doc->ItemClass->value."'".','."'".$doc->BaseUOM->value."'".')">Add</button>';
        $row[] = $doc->InventoryID->value;
        $row[] = $doc->Description->value;
        $row[] = $doc->ItemType->value;
        $row[] = $doc->ItemClass->value;
        $row[] = $doc->PostingClass->value;
        $row[] = $doc->TaxCategory->value;
        $row[] = $doc->BaseUOM->value;
        $row[] = $doc->ItemStatus->value;
        foreach ($doc->WarehouseDetails as $doc1) {
            $row[] = $doc1->QtyOnHand->value;
        }
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(
        'data' => $data,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
```